# no eclipse como gerar um aquivo jar do projeto?

Tags: java, eclipse

No eclipse como gerar um arquivo **.jar** do projeto para usar em outra aplicação

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localize na view Package Explorer o projeto do qual pretende gerar o arquivo JAR, clique com o botão direito e selecione a opção Export.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Wizard que se apresenta, digite a palavra “jar” na caixa de texto “Select an export destination” e será exibido diversas opções que apresentam conteúdo relevante de acordo com o que fora digitado. Selecione a opção JAR File (Java)  e clique no botão “Next”.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O próximo passo do Wizard é a janela JAR Export - onde é exibido a estrutura do projeto escolhido. Há a opção de selecionar quais as classes (recursos) que serão exportadas para dentro do JAR. Além das classes, é necessário definir o diretório e o nome do arquivo .jar que será gerado – na caixa de texto “Select the export destination – JAR File”

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aplicação que deseja adicionar o .Jar, basta clacar em Import desta vez.

Fonte: [http://blog.coding4fun.com.br/](http://blog.coding4fun.com.br/2013/09/distribuir-aplicacao-java-em-arquivo-jar-eclipse/)